# geting server IP that post data

Tags: php, http-post

I am POSTing some data from one server to another using following code:

> ```
>       $data2 = http_build_query(
>           array(
>               'desc' => $desc
>           )           );
>                   $options = array('http' =>
>           array(
>           'method'  => 'POST',
>           'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
>           'content' => $data2
>           )           );
>               $context  = stream_context_create($options);            // post request             $result = file_get_contents($payment_url, false, $context);
>       $result = @json_decode($result, true);
> ```

I would like to ensure that following POST comming from correct server so I have to check server IP posting this data. but $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] give me wrong IP (actually give me destination`s server IP instead Posting server IP).

Comment: Why not pass the IP it along with the rest of the post data?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton because it is totaly unsecure!

Comment: Ehm.. How is it totally insecure?

Comment: then POSTing server could use white listed IP for me to bypass this check.

Answer (score 0):

On the server you are posting the data to, you can obtain the ip address of the device making the request by using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` like such:

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if($ip_address == 'Your.Server.Ip.Address.'){

    // do stuff

} else {

    // deny request

}
```

The variable you are currently using `SERVER_ADDR` lists the ip address of the server executing the script. For more information about php's $_SERVER variable, check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) as they do a good job of explaining everything.

Another option if you would rather handle this at the server level would be to restrict access to the directory in which the script resides by ip address. [This article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-restrict-access-based-on-ip-address-to-selected-directories/) explains this in good detail (if your on apache).